# Dialogflow deploys not happening

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es

Have a situation where my Dialogflow deploys are not happening as expected. I am using the inline editor and hitting the 'Deploy' button, however, my code changes are not being propagated to Google Cloud Functions.

The following message is logged on Cloud Functions for my dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment function:
Warning, estimating Firebase Config based on GCLOUD_PROJECT. Initializing firebase-admin may fail

I am not using firebase-admin in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I got the 'Warning, estimating Firebase Config based on GCLOUD_PROJECT. Initializing firebase-admin may fail' error today as well, but my project worked as expected.

A few quick thoughts:

1. Did you find this message impacted your Dialogflow agent's ability to fulfill your intent?
2. Did you remember to include the following at the start of your index.js file?

   ```
   // import the firebase-functions package for deployment.
   const functions = require('firebase-functions');
   ```